# Component Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'board[rowSet][colSet]')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a Mine Field game with React Native, but I can't render the MineField component.
I think the error is on spreadMines function, I don't know if it is because I'm using class components and it needs to use .bind() method or some code are incorrect.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUB0i.jpg)

**App.jsx:**

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.createState();
  }

  minesAmount = () => {
    const cols = params.getColumsAmount();
    const rows = params.getRowsAmount();
    return Math.ceil(cols * rows * params.difficultLevel);
  };

  createState = () => {
    const cols = params.getColumsAmount();
    const rows = params.getRowsAmount();
    return {
      board: createMinedBoard(rows, cols, this.minesAmount()),
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Iniciando o MineField!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.introcdution}>
          Tamanho da grade: {params.getRowsAmount()}x {params.getColumsAmount()}
          y
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.board}>
          <MineField board={this.state.board.bind(this)} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Functions.js: (The game logics file)**

```js
const createBoard = (rows, columns) => {
  return Array(rows)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, row) => {
      return Array(columns)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, column) => {
          return {
            row,
            column,
            opened: false,
            flagged: false,
            mined: false,
          };
        });
    });
};

const spreadMines = (board, minesAmount) => {
  const rows = board.lenght;
  const columns = board[0].lenght;
  let minesPlanted = 0;

  while (minesPlanted < minesAmount) {
    //O segundo parâmetro é a base;
    const rowSel = parseInt(Math.random() * rows, 10);
    const colSel = parseInt(Math.random() * columns, 10);

    if (!board[rowSel][colSel].mined) {
      board[rowSel][colSel].mined = true;
      minesPlanted++;
    }
  }
};

const createMinedBoard = (rows, columns, minesAmount) => {
  const board = createBoard(rows, columns);
  spreadMines(board, minesAmount);
  return board;
};

export { createMinedBoard };
```

**And the MineField component:**

```js
export default ({ board }) => {
  const rows = board.map((row, r) => {
    const columns = row.map((field, c) => {
      return <Field {...field} key={c} />;
    });
    return <View key={r}>{columns}</View>;
  });
  return <View style={mineFieldStyle.container}>{rows}</View>;
};
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message and any accompanying stacktrace? Also, what is `spreadMines`? I see no reference to it in your snippets.

Comment: @DrewReese Oh man, sorry, the code in Functions.js file was the same as in the App.jsx file, can you see the function spreadMines now?

Comment: Typo? `const rows = board.lenght;` should be `const rows = board.length;`. Same with columns. If this is just a typo in creating your question do you have this code available in a *running* codesandbox, or a repo we could clone and run, to debug further? It's still very clear what your error is, and the screen cap of the code isn't helpful.

Comment: Issue seems to be caused by a typo, voting to close as "Unreproducible/Caused by Typo".